# Data Recovery of external HDD

Tags: data-recovery

I have 1 TB of external Seagate Backup plus HDD. 
I accidentally erased it while i was trying to update ubuntu, during the install process.
In ubuntu the HDD shows nothing, but if i open that drive in windows 8, it shows files and folder with weird names. (for eg. ≈ⁿ0╗ ∞5.Ç=σ      |w▒ε╢.nΦ5     ╝'Xf%Äå.|     ▀█┴,iï└.╨▓)

Now, I want to recover this HDD using a recovery tool. I have not made any changes to the HDD and I am wondering what is the best recovery tool and how much would be possible to recover, if at all?

Which ever option is better, please suggest the software best suited for my situation!!

Thanks already..
ds

Comment: if your file system was ext3 formatted, then you can use `ext3grep` to recover.

Comment: "windows recovery tool" = off topic. "o recover it using ubuntu recovery tool or windows?" Why ask this? ALL OF US will say Ubuntu since this is AskUbuntu.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case I recommend using `tesdisk` (To recover the partition) or `photorec` (to recover the files). Both of which are installed using:

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

After that, in the terminal type sudo testdisk`if you wish to recover the partition or`sudo photorec` if you wish to recover files. Know that you need another hard drive (Not another partition) if you want to recover the files correctly and with less chance of fails.

Also please read: [Testdisk or gpart for recovering lost partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269973/testdisk-or-gpart-for-recovering-lost-partitions/269988#269988)